# Error en la parte 3 de django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema en la parte 3 del tutorial de django link  ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/intro/tutorial03/ ), en la sección - Escribiendo mas vistas - hago todo como sale en la tutorial pero al actualizar la pagina me lanza un error, les adjuntare la imagen para que sea mas detallado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Les muestro la referencia de la pagina cuando la actualizo, donde aprecia el link de esta.
Mi código de urls.py y lo que me lanza el cmd

Mi código en models.py

```py
    import datetime
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone


    # Create your models here.

    class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def __str__(self):
            return self.question_text

        def was_published_recently(self):
            return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - 
     datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    class Choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        def __str__(self):
           return self.choice_text
```

Código en views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    # Create your views here.

    def hola(request):
        return HttpResponse("Welcome!")

    def detail(request, question_id):
        return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

    def results(request, question_id):
        response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
        return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

    def vote(request, question_id):
        return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Código en urls.py (blogmio)

```py
   from django.urls import path
   from . import views 


   urlpatterns = [
       path('blogmio/', views.hola),
       # ex: /polls/5/
       path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
       # ex: /polls/5/results/
       path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
       # ex: /polls/5/vote/
       path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),

   ]
```

código en urls.py (sitio)

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('', include('blogmio.urls')),
     ]
```

código de admin.py

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import *

    # Register your models here.

    admin.site.register(Question)
```

Comment: Hola! agrega tu código en formato de texto por favor

Comment: Listo amigo ya se lo anexe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He mirado el tutorial que seguiste, y he encontrado que te haz saltado unos pasos o quizás no haz entendido bien:

1. En el [Tutorial parte 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) se puede apreciar que ha colocado el nombre de la url `polls` (que en tu caso es `blogmio`) en las `urls.py` del sitio:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
   # path('polls/', include('polls.urls')), en lugar de polls aquí iría blogmio/
    path('blogmio/', include('blogmio.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Lo anterior es el nombre principal de la url de `blogmio` a través de él se podrá acceder a todas las urls que pongas en `blogmio/urls.py`:

```py
 from django.urls import path
   from . import views 


   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.hola), #aquí se deja en blanco*
       # ex: /polls/5/
       path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
       # ex: /polls/5/results/
       path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
       # ex: /polls/5/vote/
       path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),

   ]
```

- Se deja en blanco, ya que al llamar a `127.0.0.1:8000/blogmio` entrará a la vista `hola` ya que `blogmio`, ya está previamente en las `urls.py` del sitio

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto soluciono mi problema, excelente servicio 5 estrellas

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado, son errores pequeños pero que dan un dolor de cabeza horrible... pero entre programadoras nos ayudamos querida :)